# How to show loading bar while clicking on fragments

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with fragments, which takes sometime to load the fragments. How to add a progress bar while loading the fragments. Here's my code

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                activity.startActivity(new Intent(context,ActivityQuote.class)
                     .putExtra("title",modelCategory.get(position).getTitle())
                     .putExtra("category", modelCategory.get(position).getCategory()));
        });
```

Comment: You can use `AsyncTask` for this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: Don't do any long-running task during fragment load, update/manipulate your data after creating the views of the fragments.

Comment: Well in this case , **adding a loading bar would freeze up the UI to some more extent**